# How to set up turtles between boundaries, on only colored patches?

Tags: model, netlogo

I'm trying to set up turtles on only on the white patches. Which white patch doesn't matter. I want to do this by the use of coordinates (creating boarders), not the patch color. However, my code gives an error: "With expected this input to be an agentset, but got a number instead". Does someone knows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code keeps getting cleaner and cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setxy` [only takes two arguments](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/setxy.html)- an x value and a y value. You are passing it invalid calls to `random-xcor` and `random-ycor`. Instead, you likely want to generate random numbers within a range (for example, > -1 and < 6 for x). There are several ways to do this, but the easiest is probably using something like `random` or `range`:

A random version:

```
setxy ( 0 + random 6 ) ( 5 + random 1 )
```

A range version:

```
setxy one-of (range 0 6) one-of (range 5 7)
```

As an aside, you can streamline your setup call a little by extending your `with` statement to include both `pxcor` and `pycor` arguments:

```
  ask patches with [ pxcor >= 0 and pxcor < 6 and pycor >= 5 and pycor < 7 ] [
    set pcolor white 
  ]
```